# Laravel getCountForPagination() returning Object instead of int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I am trying to get the number of results with

```
$total = $this->query->getCountForPagination();
```

And instead of receiving an (int) like I see on the documentation, a `object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder)` is returned

The function is called from Query/Builder.php class which returns an int .. but I think it gets converted somehow along the way.

Any reason for that ?

Comment: What is `$this->query`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use: `$total = $this->query->getQuery()->getCountForPagination();`

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. Any idea why does it need ->getQuery() though ? with query->getCountForPagination() it was entering the right function .. it just didn't return what it should.

Comment: Without `getQuery()` it returns `$this` from `__call` function in  `Eloquent\Builder` class

Comment: Is there any performance benefits for using getCountForPagination() instead of count() method?

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel version ^10 you can use:

```
$total = $this->query->getBaseQuery()->getCountForPagination();
```